# Saving a multi dimensional array to image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, gis, scikit-image

I have an array containing 10 spectral band in python and I want to export it to a tiff image with 10 spectral band separated in the same file.

I tried with skimage but the problem that I am obtaining the wanted image with the right component (x, y, bands nb) but only when I am reading the image with python, but when I am trying to read it with c++ I cannot obtain the right components as the y component doesn't exist anymore.

This is mu code which takes in parameter multiple images from the command line and bind them in multi spectral image :

```
from sys import argv
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
import os

def bindImage(*argv):
    # Open multiple images and bind them all
    k = 0
    exported_img = np.zeros((imread(argv[1]).shape[0], imread(argv[1]).shape[1], len(argv)))
    print exported_img.shape #in my case it gives me (2100, 2100, 10)
    while(k < len(argv)):
         img = imread(argv[k])
         exported_img[:,:,k] = labeled[:,:]
         k+=1
    imsave("binded_and_labled_image.tiff", exported_img[:,:,:], plugin="tifffile")

def main():
    bindImage(*argv[1:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

So how can I save my image file in order to obtain an image with multi spectral band and keep using it with multi programming language.

Comment: Please post the code you used to write and read the TIFF.

Comment: I have added the code below. Please check it if there is a solution for my issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to specify PhotometricInterpretation and PlanarConfiguration, e.g `imsave("test.tiff", np.zeros((2100, 2100, 10), dtype='uint8'), plugin="tifffile", photometric='minisblack', planarconfig='contig')`. Should work with the latest tifffile.

Comment: That looks like the right solution, I am testing it tomorrow on the work's machine and I will give my feed back. But before that, @cgohlke can you please explain the role of those parameters in skimage imsave. Thnx a lot.